# I am uploading 5 files at a time, how can I update a particular file?

Tags: php, file-upload

i am uploading 5 files at a time.its uploaded successfully but when i want to update some particular files like file 1 and file 2 other files should not be changed it must be as its is..but in my case it goes blank..here is my code

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['update']))
{
    $img1 = $_FILES['file_img1']['name'];
        $fileElementName = 'file_img1';
        $path = 'upload/'; 
        $location = $path . $_FILES['file_img1']['name']; 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_img1']['tmp_name'], $location); 

    $img2 = $_FILES['file_img2']['name'];
        $fileElementName = 'file_img2';
        $path = 'upload/'; 
        $location = $path . $_FILES['file_img2']['name']; 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_img2']['tmp_name'], $location); 

    $img3 = $_FILES['file_img3']['name'];
        $fileElementName = 'file_img3';
        $path = 'upload/'; 
        $location = $path . $_FILES['file_img3']['name']; 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_img3']['tmp_name'], $location); 

    $img4 = $_FILES['file_img4']['name'];
        $fileElementName = 'file_img4';
        $path = 'upload/'; 
        $location = $path . $_FILES['file_img4']['name']; 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_img4']['tmp_name'], $location); 

    $img5 = $_FILES['file_img5']['name'];
        $fileElementName = 'file_img5';
        $path = 'upload/'; 
        $location = $path . $_FILES['file_img5']['name']; 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_img5']['tmp_name'], $location); 

$sel="update tbl_job_schedule set
            file1='$img1',
            file2='$img2',
            file3='$img3',
            file4='$img4',
            file5='$img5',
            status='schwork',
            user_cmntdate=now(),
            cmnt='".$_REQUEST['addcmnt']."' where clientname='".$rw['clientname']."' and username='".$_SESSION['user']."' and jobdate='".$_SESSION['strmonth']."-".$_REQUEST['dt']."-".$_SESSION['yy']."'";
            mysql_query($sel) or die($sel);
    }
```

Comment: And why did you tag this with `css`?

Comment: Regarding your question, I think you should try to compare the _properties_ of the files going in with the ones you already uploaded to check for differences, and only then commit the files that did change to the server.

Answer (score 0):

check whether all the parameters are not empty before updating the database,you will get the answer of your problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put if condition to check file is present or not

```
     if(isset($_REQUEST['update']))
   {
      if($_FILES['file_img1']['name']!=""){
    $img1 = $_FILES['file_img1']['name'];
    $fileElementName = 'file_img1';
    $path = 'upload/'; 
    $location = $path . $_FILES['file_img1']['name']; 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_img1']['tmp_name'], $location); 
         $str.='file1="$img1",';
           }
      .......

       $sel="update tbl_job_schedule set
               ".$str."
        status='schwork',
        user_cmntdate=now(),
        cmnt='".$_REQUEST['addcmnt']."' where clientname='".$rw['clientname']."' and username='".$_SESSION['user']."' and jobdate='".$_SESSION['strmonth']."-".$_REQUEST['dt']."-".$_SESSION['yy']."'";
        mysql_query($sel) or die($sel);
}
```

Comment: i dont want check if its null or not.i have already inserted 5 files and now with this code i want to update particular files like if i upload file_img1 and file_img2 it should be updated but other 3 files should not be updated it should be as it is...but in my case other 3 files goes null...how can i check??..i have already tried your conditional code ..